# C# Stop Task under Form_Show()

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Hi I have read other tutorials but could not figure it out. I am running a task and when task is completed I want to hide the current form and load another form but It hangs and nothing is displayed. This is my code please guide me -

```html
public Loading()
{
       InitializeComponent();
       Shown += Loading_Shown;
}
private void Loading_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       label2.Text = "Step 1...";
       Task.Run(() =>
       {
            if (Directory.Exists(contentPath))
            {
                filePresent = false;
            }

            if (filesPresent == false)
            {
                BeginInvoke(
                (MethodInvoker)delegate 
                    { 
                        label2.Text = "Downloading Files..."; 
                    }
                 );

                 Directory.CreateDirectory(contentPath);
                 Home form = new Home();
                 form.Visible = true;
             }

             else
             {
                  Home form = new Home();
                  form.Visible = true;
             }
       });
}
```

The other form loads half and screen hangs. Please guide me how to continue with this. Thanks

Comment: You are running Task Synchronously instead of Asynchronously so code will block until task is completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't create the second form "when [the] task is completed", but *inside* that task. So you create the second form on a different thread than the first one. This is a bad idea.

One solution is to make `Loading_Shown` an `async` method and `await` the task. Then, when the task *really has completed* and control flow returned to the original *ui* thread, you can create the second form:

```
private async void Loading_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label2.Text = "Step 1...";
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // different thread
        filePresent = Directory.Exists(contentPath);
        if (!filePresent) Directory.CreateDirectory(contentPath);
    });

    // back on UI thread
    if (!filesPresent)
    {
        label2.Text = "Downloading Files..."; });

        Home form = new Home();
        form.Visible = true;
    }
    else{
        Home form = new Home();
        form.Visible = true;
    }
}
```